# Survey/references on random geometric $K$-NN – $K$-nearest-neighbour graphs?

Tags: reference-request, graph-theory, random-graphs

[Edit:] Some related info on number of connected components of NN-graphs can be found here: https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/a/47037/2408

---

Sample $N$ points in $\mathbb{R}^d$ from some distribution $f$, e.g. uniform $[0,1]^d$, or Gaussian $\mathcal{N}(0,1)^d$, or whatever...

**Question 1:** What is known/survey/references on [$K$-nearest-neighbor graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nearest_neighbor_graph) for such data clouds ? 
(that means we connect each point with $K$ its nearest neighbors). At least for some distributions $f$ like uniform or Gaussian ?

**Question 2:** For example what is known about degrees distribution ? Simulations suggest it is [power-law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scale-free_network), what is the exponent depending on $d$ and $f$?

There is good survey on Wikipedia - [Geometric random graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_geometric_graph), but a little bit different class of graphs is considered there. I.e. points are connected if the distance is shorter than threshold $r$ (and, well, distribution is only uniform). 
It is more common in practical applications to consider $K$-NN graphs, rather than GRG, by the clear reason - the size of graph is $K\times N$, while for GRG you might get $N^2$ (in the worst case).

**Question 3** Is there a way looking on $K$-NN graph to estimate dimension $d$ of the space,
at least for uniform/Gaussian distributions ? 
Somewhat similar as  "[cluster coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clustering_coefficient)" of GRG [depends only on the dimension $d$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_geometric_graph#Clustering_coefficient):

[image]

**Question 4:** Is there an estimate of clustering coefficient for $K$-NN graph ?

**Question 5:** If one considers minimal spanning tree for $K$-NN graph, what is known about it ? Degree distribution ?

I am aware about the following beautiful result on the [length estimate for Euclidean MST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_minimum_spanning_tree#Expected_size):
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The wikipedia article on random geometric graphs only scratches the surface. A much deeper treatment is provided in Mathew Penrose's amazing text *[Random Geometric Graphs](https://www.worldcat.org/title/random-geometric-graphs/oclc/51316118)*. Chapter 4 contains a treatment of what you are asking about, namely the "empirical distribution of nearest-neighbour distances amongst the points." Also, the underlying distribution of the points does *not* need to be uniform. You can feed in any underlying distribution and run a $\chi^2$-test to see if that distribution is a good fit, based on a $k$-NN statistic. Penrose says this was considered by [Bickel and Breiman](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.aop/1176993668). Penrose cites a [book by Silverman](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0412246201) for more on this kind of thing.

Penrose also cites a [monograph by Yukich](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783540636663) that I have not read. About this monograph, Penrose writes (emphasis mine)

> Related graph constructions include those **where the decision on
> whether to connect two nearby points depends not only on the distance
> between them, but also on the positions of other points**. Such
> constructions include the minimal spanning tree, and also graphs such
> as the nearest-neighbour graph and the Delaunay graph; in the latter,
> points lying in neighbouring Voronoi cells are connected. For many of
> these related graph constructions, some of the asymptotic theory is
> described in Yukich (1998). For further results see Penrose and Yukich
> (2001, 2003).